# error getResource() in another class

Tags: android, android-studio, bitmap, resources, android-resources

this code **not** in class mainActivity

Error :

```
 cannot find symbol method getResources()
```

Code :

```
public void printPhoto(int img) {

        try {
            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    img);
            if(bmp!=null){
                byte[] boleh = Utils.decodeBitmap(bmp);
                mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.ESC_ALIGN_CENTER);
                printText(boleh);
            }else{
                Log.e("Print Photo error", "the file isn't exists");
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("PrintTools", "the file isn't exists");
        }

    }
```

> All of my function and method in another class. In my MainActivity just for button and listener. how to solve this. I am beginner in android studio. thanks

Comment: Are you using fragment?

Comment: You need a context to call getResources(). So call should be context.getResources()
Activity is a context, so you can try to pass a reference to it to your class

Answer (score 1):

You should pass [**`Context`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html).

**Code**

```
public void printPhoto(Context ctx,int img) {

    try {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(ctx.getResources(),
                img);
```

**Call**

```
printPhoto(YourActivityName.this, R.drawable.your_image); // For Activity
printPhoto(getActivity(), R.drawable.your_image); // For Fragment
```

Comment: Error:(308, 36) error: not an enclosing class: MainActivity . I got this from printPhoto(MainActivity.this, R.drawable.img);

Comment: @IsaHerdyanto try with `printPhoto(this, R.drawable.img);` or `printPhoto(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.img);` . Hope this works.

Comment: check your email sir

Answer (score 0):

Pass the `Context` from your `MainActivity` class to you custom class. Follow it -

```
public void printPhoto(Context context, int img) {

    try {
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(),
                img);
        if(bmp!=null){
            byte[] boleh = Utils.decodeBitmap(bmp);
            mmOutputStream.write(PrinterCommands.ESC_ALIGN_CENTER);
            printText(boleh);
        }else{
            Log.e("Print Photo error", "the file isn't exists");
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("PrintTools", "the file isn't exists");
    }

}
```

And call it from your `MainActivity`.

```
printPhoto(getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.img);
```